# Can you mount SMB shares in Kubuntu like in Ubuntu?

Tags: samba, kubuntu, dolphin

I have just installed Kubuntu, and I notice that Dolphin tries to access SMB shares using libsmbclient instead of mounting an SMB location like I am used to in Nautilus. Unfortunately, the performance is horrendous, and for some reason, I am unable to access shares that I could access in Nautilus (it gives me authorization issues which I didn't have in the SMB mounts).

Is there a way to mount SMB shares in Kubuntu as in Ubuntu?

(Note: I am accessing the share over a VPN, in case that makes a difference, but I don't see why it should, and in Nautilus the performance was completely accetable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using command line tools like [smbmount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smbmount). This will mount the dir, KDE or Gnome , you will always be able to mount. Eventually you can put it into `/etc/fstab`, but when starting up without network or connected to another network the mount will not succeed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should probably rephrase my question, because I actually want mounting of an SMB share in the file manager (Dolphin) in the same way that it works in Nautilus. For now I will +1, but I will accept your answer otherwise and perhaps post a more specific question after. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution:

1. Create `/media/MOUNTPOINT`
2. Install `cifs-tools` package
3. Add to fstab the line:

   ```
   //IP_SAMBA_SERVER/SHARE /media/MOUNTPOUNT cifs user,noauto,user=smb_username,password=smbpasswd 0 0
   ```

   - After that, it will appear a new icon in Dolphin with MOUNTPOINT name. By clicking on it, it will mount the SMB share.
   - NOTE: For security reasons, may be better to use the option "credentials" instead user & password. Check man mount.cifs to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The Dolphin, and Konqueror file manager/browsers both support cifs.  Just input `smb://my_windows_server/my_share_name/`  or `smb://myuser@my_windows_server/my_share_name/` in the *url* field.  With dolphin the bar is hidden, but you can open it by clicking on network in the side bar or clicking after the icon for your current location.

PS - `Smbmount` is not really used in modern linux systems.  If you want to mount the filesystem the example using cifs tools is more likely to work.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but the problem still applies to users who have the same problem with the current kUbuntu 14.04 LTS.

You can use Smb4k

[image: screenshot]

I did the following in a fresh install of kUbuntu 14.04.4 LTS

```
sudo apt-get install smb4k
```

1. Go to application launcher and type smb4k, then click or enter to run.
2. Click on the tab at the bottom left that says “Network Neighborhood”
3. Browse for your network shares (Windows, smb/samba, etc). My shares
   are username/password protected so when I tried to access them, it
   prompted me for login details and after entering them the shares
   were automatically mounted.
4. After it’s mounted, you can use the default file manager (Dolphin)
   to browse, access files, play movies, etc.

More info on Smb4k at [kde-apps.org](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=9814&forumpage=5), [userbase.kde.org/Smb4K](https://userbase.kde.org/Smb4K) or go to [docs.kde.org](https://docs.kde.org/) and type smb4k in application name.