# How to install from an external repo in my work network (problem with spaces)

Tags: 12.04, networking

I'm very new with Ubuntu and I want to install packages from a repository located in my network. So:

I first edited sources list using:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Inside sources list I commented everything so it doesn't try to update packages from internet and added the address where the repository is located:

```
deb file:/home/ragnar/.gvfs/shared%20on%20ubuntu-i3/mydebs ./
```

I tried to change every "space" with %20, but it still doesn't find it on the network.

So, after `sudo apt-get update` it throws:

```
Ign file: ./ InRelease
Ign file: ./ Release.gpg
Ign file: ./ Release
Err file: ./ Packages
  File not found
Ign file: ./ Translation-en_US
Ign file: ./ Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch file:/home/ragnar/.gvfs/shared on ubuntu-i3/mydebs/./Packages  File not found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So, can I change the file name "shared on ubuntu" inside .gvfs so it doesn't have any spaces, or is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

Well, I replaced `%20` with `\` and got the next output (It's important to say that just before replacing it I did `sudo apt-get update` and got exactly the same output):

```
Ign file: ./ InRelease
Ign file: ./ Release.gpg                   
Ign file: ./ Release                       
Err file: ./ Packages                      
  File not found
Ign file: ./ Translation-en_US             
Ign file: ./ Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [316 B]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release [12.9 kB]                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources/DiffIndex                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex             
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex [199 B]          
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources [1,101 B]                 
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages [1,962 B]           
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en [2,123 B]          
Fetched 18.6 kB in 24s (764 B/s)                                              
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 32B18A1260D8DA0B
W: Failed to fetch file:/home/ragnar/.gvfs/shared\on\ubuntu-i3/mydebs/./Packages  File not found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Try using `fstab` and cifs-tools to mount it to custom mount point: http://askubuntu.com/a/215533/158442

Comment: Looks like spaces are not a problem. Is it a valid repo with `Packages` and other related files? Compare with a normal one.

Comment: Well, the repo works fine in the host computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-)  Use `\ ` (backslash[space]) instead of `%20` and report back, please...  (and don't run off without coming back as this still has to be converted to an answer...)  I'm not 100% sure until you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Well I managed to resolve the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install smbclient smbfs
```

`smbclient` needs to see the shared resources on the network and `smbfs` needs to be able to mount a shared resource on your computer.

So, you just have to write:

```
sudo mount -t smbfs //IP_address/shared_folder /home/username/my_folder -o user=username
```

Then I edited the file `sources.list` and everything worked out fine.